# Notice (8): Undefined offset: 4 [APP/Controller/UniController.php, line 69]

Tags: php, cakephp

I am new to the `cakephp`.
I want to know how to retrieve the array values(Specific Key values).
The result value as:

```
Array(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 14
)
```

Here I want to retrieve the value of key 4.How to retrieve it? I am trying by this method. Is it correct or not?

```
echo $details[4];
```

Comment: please show your code where you are having this error

Answer (score 0):

If that array is called $details, then `echo $details[4];` should show `14` but, as @Eagle says, it's likely that something else is going wrong and, without being able to see what you are doing, it's very difficult to help.